# Configuring Linux to use Windows proxy

Tags: windows, linux, proxy

I need a Debian box (without X) to use a Windows proxy server with authentication.

Normally I can do this with the env variable:

```
http_proxy=http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```

Unfortunately, the Windows domain is complicating things.

In a nutshell, how do I configure Debian to use a proxy where authentication requires a Windows domain and username like `domain\myname`?

Comment: Have you thought about supplying the username as username@fqdn?

Comment: Have you tried a double backslash?

Comment: Yes, my first thought was to double backslash, but no luck. Single quotes also didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

I think that your "Windows Proxy" is a proxy that requires NTLM authentication (username, password, Windows domain). The typical example is Microsoft ISA server, the standard proxy server for large corporate environments running a Windows environment.

If you must go through an NTLM proxy, use `CNTLM` ([sourceforge](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net)) between you and the company's proxy. It stores your NTLM credentials and uses them to talk to the company's proxy, presenting you with a local proxy (i.e. `localhost:3128`) you can connect to with no authentication required.

Your configuration would then look like:

- CNTLM set up to point to your company's proxy, `proxy.big-company.com:8080`, with your credentials `user = jsmith`, `pass = god123`, `domain = BIGCOMPANY`, and local proxy port `localhost:3128`
- your `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable set to `localhost:3128`

[More about it in my answer to this question on Server Fault.](https://serverfault.com/questions/175495/apt-get-through-ntlm-authenticated-proxy)

Answer (score 8):

[RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) defines the syntax of a URL, and it allows for characters to be encoded using hexadecimal representation.  So if a double-backslash doesn't work you should try

```
http_proxy=http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```

or

```
http_proxy=http://USERNAME%40DOMAIN:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```

(noting that %5C is the encoding for a backslash and %40 is the encoding for the [at sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/@).)

Comment: Upvote because this set me in the right direction. I'm using curl to download packages, and found this page helpful: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/400379-problems-ntlm-proxy-authentication.html